# How to force https via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have an app that uses a number of aliases and I want to ensure visitors to each site is always redirected to https.

So I have added this rule to my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When visiting http://example.com they are redirected to https://www.example.com

However, when they visit: www.example.com they are not re-directed to the https domain.

Is there a simple way to force all domains to https://www. without having to explicitly mention each domain?

Comment: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how-to-force-ssl-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Change your rewrites to this rules. First catch all https:// and http:// non www domain requests and redirect to https://www.requested-domain. Second catch all other http://www domain requests and redirect to https://www.requested-domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This seems to create a redirect loop unfortunately.

Comment: First catch all `non www (http:// and https://)`, second `http://www`, default is https: // www... where is loop? Rules in this order should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I did

```js
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```